# Scrape text inside SPAN unsing beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How can I extract the text from `<span class="arabic_sanad arabic">` & `<span class="arabic_text_details arabic">` from the below

```
<div class="arabic_hadith_full arabic"><span class="arabic_sanad arabic">حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو الْيَمَانِ، قَالَ أَخْبَرَنَا شُعَيْبٌ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو الزِّنَادِ، عَنِ الأَعْرَجِ، عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ ـ رضى الله عنه ـ أَنَّ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ ‏</span>
<span class="arabic_text_details arabic">"‏ فَوَالَّذِي نَفْسِي بِيَدِهِ لاَ يُؤْمِنُ أَحَدُكُمْ حَتَّى أَكُونَ أَحَبَّ إِلَيْهِ مِنْ وَالِدِهِ وَوَلَدِهِ ‏"</span><span class="arabic_sanad arabic">‏‏.‏</span></div>
```

I have tried the following, but i am failing as per error below

```
print name2
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 2-11: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**CODE:**

```
url = "http://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/8"

parser = etree.HTMLParser()
html   = etree.parse(url, parser)
result = etree.tostring(html.getroot(), pretty_print=True, method="html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(result) 

results = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "actualHadithContainer"})
for result in results :
  ar = result.find("div", {"class" : "arabic_hadith_full arabic"})
  name2 = ar.get_text()
  print name2
```

Comment: try with `print u"{}".format(name2)`. More info: http://goo.gl/Mz0QMw

Comment: I get name2 = ar.get_text()
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the string to unicode, before printing it:

```
ar = result.find("div", {"class" : "arabic_hadith_full arabic"}, text=True) #only finds those with text inside
name2 = unicode(ar.get_text(), encoding='utf-8')
print name2
```

Comment: I get the following error name2 = unicode(ar.get_text(), encoding='utf-8')
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Comment: Do you want to include the `<span>` or not?

Comment: Finished updating. Check it out.

Comment: thx, but same error name2 = unicode(ar.get_text(), encoding='utf-8')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Comment: Sorry, i forgot something. Please wait, i'm going to do the isha prayer right now :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the string to unicode as pointed before.

```
 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

To prevent this error you have to check if `ar` has the `get_text` method.
What happens is that with the old code the first node has text, 
you get your error because of wrong encoding.
When you fix the program, the for loop continue and you get on a node without text,
so the `get_text` method does not exist at this point.
Something like this should work:

```
for result in results :
  ar = result.find("div", {"class" : "arabic_hadith_full arabic"})

  if not getattr(ar, get_text):
      continue

  name2 = ar.get_text()

  print u"{}".format(name2)
```

Comment: still not working, I think my problem is that there is a <span> inside the DIV and as such it fails to get the text!! maybe